# Text Direction In DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, telerik

I use telerik WinForms Components for my project

in RadGridView (Right to Left) :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8j0Us.png

It Show 0001-9999 Instead of 9999-0001

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 1):

When I tried this on a WinForms RadGridView which has the RightToLeft property set to true, I did not see the number flipped like in your example.

[image: RightToLeft Property for grid = true]

However, you can set the RadGridView RightToLeft property to true, but change the RightToLeft property for one column in the CellFormatting event.

```
private void radGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, Telerik.WinControls.UI.CellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.CellElement.ColumnInfo.Name == "ID")
  {
    e.CellElement.RightToLeft = false;
  }
}
```

You can see the difference when the ID column cells have the RightToLeft property set to false.

[image: RightToLeft Property for grid = true; cells in ID columns RightToLeft property set to false]

Comment: Thanks. this code worked great: http://128.7.img98.net/out.php/i210070_untitled1.png

Comment: I'm glad it worked. Since it worked, maybe you can check this as the accepted answer.